# Intended use of the 'variations' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

In a few articles, I see there is a tag of 'variations' on them.

There are 2 possible meanings that I can see for this tag:

- Variations of a particular opening or even middlegame and endgame positions.
- Chess variants, such as Suicide, Bughous etc.

'Variations' currently does not have a definition, so it's currently being used for both cases above.

My question would be, which definition should 'variations' be?  perhaps a new tag for chess variations be created? i.e. 'variants' or 'chess-variants'?

Comment: When a consensus is reached, please remember to add tag wiki excerpts (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/) to clarify the purpose of those tags and to clean up the tagging of the questions themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Using a variations tag to mean 'variations of a particular opening, middlegame, or endgame position' seems to add little additional information to the question.  Like a tag of 'code' on stack overflow.  Don't think we need such a generic tag, though something like 'calculation' or 'analysis' is appropriate if that's what the question is about.

Having a variants or chess-variants tag makes a lot of sense though, along with tags for specific chess variants like bughouse, atomic, etc. like you said.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Bort's answer:

As of this writing, there are 3 questions tagged [variations](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations).  On all of them, the variations tag could (and probably should) be replaced with [opening](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opening) without really losing any meaning.

There was one question referring to chess variants (specifically mentioned Chess 960).  I retagged that as [chess-variants](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-variants) just so that it is separate from the [variations](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations) questions.  [Daniel δ](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/86/daniel]) had written a fairly exhaustive tag-wiki for [variations](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variations), but the information was referring to [chess-variants](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess-variants).  I moved the tag-wiki to the correct tag and embellished some as well.

Feel free to re-tag or suggest better wording for anything as well.

Comment: I like the idea of 'variations' to denote opening variations and 'chess-variants' for just that.